# Customizing Search in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

Is there any option to completely control a Search module with a Summary view? I am struggling to get there. I have the following settings so far:

1. In admin I created an Index called PublicSearch with a number of fields.
2. I am getting a search result which is a mixture of two content parts - Question and Expert
3. I have a Part view to be used in search result for Experts called ExpertSummary.cshtml. The view only contains the following elements now:

`@model dynamic`

`<p>Expert Summary</p>`

When the search result is coming I only expect the `"Expert Summary"` to be visible in Expert region of the Search but I am getting an additional "body" section (truncated to X characters). It seems to me because "body" is selected as a field when I created the Index it is coming up.

Each Expert record has an image of expert which is coming up in the search result and When I take out `<Place Fields_MediaPicker="Content:1" />` from Placement.info it disappears, which is fine.

But I want this summary to be completely controllable in ExpertSummary.cshtml - like a two column layout where the left col will hold the expert image and the right one will hold a brief description along with some other info - but everything would be in the View - should not come from Orchard search module as defaults.

In short I want Orchard's Index and Search modules to be functional and working like it is now but the layout and information I want to control completely using custom HTML in Parts/ExpertSummary.cshtml view.

Is this at all possible? If yes, how?

Please suggest. I am completely lost my way in Orchard framework!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand your question... Orchards search returns a Summary view by default. So you need to control the layout of your summary. Use shape tracing to create a new alternate to change the layout of the summary view. So ExpertSummary won't control the entire layout, it will just control the Expert part. Then use placement to decide what to display. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info

Also, tagging questions with "orchardcms" will be more useful than "orchardcms-1.7".